# Best approach to reproduce (several) simultaneous sounds in a Flash player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

Im in the final steps of my Flash game, now I have to take care of the music/sound.

And, I figure out that I'd need to reproduce several sounds simultaneously, sounds like gun shots, explosions, screams, etc, however, these sounds are short, < 1 seconds.

So, how many sounds can I reproduce at the same time?, and what would be the best approach (what class to use, how, tips, etc) to achieve this?, considering my situation.

Thx in advance.

Comment: I don't believe there's any limit as to how many Sound instances you can create. I would just create as many as you need, and play them as many times as you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can produce as many as you want, although the results might not be what you expect. I was having 10+ firing sounds playing at the same time and it sounded terrible. I would suggest you implement some hard-limit for the amount of sounds of one type.

Take a look at what Colby from Cheezeworld did with his [SoundManager class](http://cheezeworld.com/managing-sounds-and-music-in-actionscript-3/).

You can download the full source from the [google code repository](http://code.google.com/p/cheezeworld/downloads/detail?name=ManagingSounds.zip&can=2&q=).

Comment: Sounds interesting, Ill try that one.

Answer (score 0):

I have never run into a limit on the number of [Sound](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html)
 instances I have created, but I can't think of the max.  I did a game a few months ago that probably had twenty or so going at the same time.

It is quite easy, though, to overload and distort the stereo output.  If you are planning on many sounds at the exact same time, you will probably need to adjust the volume of each via
[SoundTransform](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/SoundTransform.html) from the [SoundChannel](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html) that gets returned when you play.  Or, you can adjust the level in the audio file itself.

Comment: I would like to know how that volume/distort works in more detail, do you have a link or a detailed explanation?

Comment: Just do an experiment where you play a whole bunch of instances of the audio file at the same time, and listen to what it sounds like.  Then adjust the volumes, and listen again.